# How to apply conditions on lines that have the same ID

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like :

```
df= [ ID  child_ID  STATUS1  
      123  11        OK    
      123  22        KO 
      123  23        OK 
      124  56        OK  
      124  45        OK
```

I want to get a final status by ID,if one of the childid is KO it means that my finalstatus is KO so i want a dataframe like :

```
f= [      ID  Child_ID  STATUS1  Statusfinal
          123  11           OK       KO
          123  22           KO       KO
          123  23           OK       KO
          124  56           OK       OK
          124  45           OK       OK
```

how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I would first compute an additional boolean column and then use a groupby aggregation:

```
resul = df.assign(FinalStatus = ((df['STATUS1'].str.lower() == 'ok') &
                  (df['STATUS2'].str.lower() == 'ok'))
          ).groupby('ID').agg({'STATUS1': 'first',
                   'STATUS2': 'first',
                   'FinalStatus': all}).reset_index()
```

Add correct labels on the last column and that's all:

```
resul['FinalStatus'] = np.where(resul['FinalStatus'], 'OK', 'KO')
```

gives:

```
   ID STATUS1 STATUS2 FinalStatus
0  12      OK      OK          KO
1  13      OK      OK          OK
```

Comment: when i tried ur way i got an error in the last command  :   ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: I cannot guess what your data really is. Please provide a [mcve] so that I can reproduce.

Comment: i managed to have only one status to check on , so i changed my question i hope u have an answer ! thanks